# Construction in Euclidean Geometry

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I came across the following problem in my Euclidean Geometry text:

Construct a triangle given the ratio of an altitude to the base, the vertical angle (the angle opposite the base), and a median to a lateral side.

I started with the given vertical angle at a point B and tried to first construct a similar triangle to the sought for one, by choosing an arbitrary ratio m:n for base and altitude. I also choose B as the center of similitude. However I can't seem to figure out how to incorporate the median. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Once you have constructed a triangle similar to the one you want, you can use the median to rescale it to the right size (draw the corresponding median in the triangle you constructed; the ratio of the result to the "true" median is the rescaling factor).

Comment: There are two solutions, in general.

Comment: There are really 8 solutions:) grouped in 4 which are mirror/rotations.

Comment: @Kelly Did the hints worked for you?

Comment: @Moti yes they did! I used homothety to rescale the similar triangle to the sought for one.